# Raspberry Pi 3B+: Camera V1.3 is not working

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, opencv, python

**My goal** is to make pictures with a simple Python3 (OpenCV) script.

**The problem** is that the camera can not be used by all the tools I have tried. But it shows up at "*/dev/video*".

**My hardware is**:

- Raspberry Pi 3 B+
- Raspberry Pi camera V1.3 (same issue with V2.1) (they are both working on a Jetson Nano/Raspi4)

**This is my setup**:

1. Installation of the Raspberry Pi OS Full (released: 2021-10-30)
2. Activation of these interfaces in the Raspi-Config: Camera, SSH, VNC, I2C
3. Checks, if the camera is found/working

**I tried the follwing things** (those are not the all of them):

- libcamera-hello Main errors: "*libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate*" and "*what():  failed to import fd 21*"
- raspistill/raspivid (I reinstalled it) Error: "*mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)*"
- changing the driver in the "*/boot/config.txt*" file (ov5647, imx219, vc4-fkms-v3d, vc4-kms-v3)
- vcgencmd get_camera Output: "*supported=0 detected=0*"
- I stopped VNC, because someone had a similar problem and was able to fix it by stopping VNC.

I did **a lot of research (~10h)** and trial and error. But was not able to get any picture out of the camera.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
libcamera-hello --qt-preview
```

I think that while using VNC or remote desktop the HW acceleration is not enabled. Also try to enable [glamor HW acceleration](https://www.arducam.com/docs/cameras-for-raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-libcamera-guide/)

Comment: Also passing the parameter when taking photo works `libcamera-still --qt-preview -o test.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are trying a very basic example such as this one:

```
import cv2
  
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(True):
    ret, frame = vid.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
vid.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

To make that work you need to run the program as admin (e.g., `sudo python test.py`). Then report back the error messages you get.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

I got the following error:
`[ WARN:0] global /home/pi/Downloads/opencv-4.5.4/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (890) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/camera_test3.py", line 6, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4) /home/pi/Downloads/opencv-4.5.4/modules/core/src/array.cpp:2494: error: (-206:Bad flag (parameter or structure field)) Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function 'cvGetMat'`

Comment: Could you connect a webcam to a USB port and then try again? Also vary the index if it does not work, i.e. `cv2.VideoCapture(1)` instead of `cv2.VideoCapture(0)`. If it works with a USB webcam, you know that the OpenCV and Python installation is correct. Always use `sudo`!

Comment: I tried these things. But it's not a USB Camera. And yes I am fully aware of `sudo`

Comment: I know it is not a USB camera. But *if* a USB camera works, then you know it is not a software problem but a problem of the RasPi hardware.